# What are the sylow subgroups of $Z_{24}$?

Tags: group-theory

I know that $|Z_{24}|=24=2^3. 3$, So we can use the equation $t=1+k\,p$ to find the number of sylow groups for each $p=2,3$. Therefore we have $1$ or $4$ sylow $3$-subgroups and $1$ or $3$ sylow $2$-subgroups.

Is $<(12)>$  the Sylow $2$-subgroup and $<(8)>$ the sylow $3$-subgroup?

Is that right?

Are there any others?

Thanks.

Comment: you have to find actual sylow subgroups and since $\mathbb{Z}_{24}$ is cyclic that's easily done since subgroups of a cyclic group are cyclic.

Comment: Think what will be the order of sylow 2- subgroup and sylow 3- subgroup respectively and combine it with my previous comment.

Comment: @MorganRodgers, Is there one Sylow 2-subgroup or 4 because $t=1+2 k$ gives $1$ and $4$.

Comment: @MorganRodgers, So we have $<3>$ as the sylow $2$-subgroup and $<8>$ as the sylow $3$-subgroup. is that right?

Comment: @MorganRodgers, So is my last comment true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $\mathbb{Z}_{24}$ is abelian, all subgroups are normal; all Sylow $p$-subgroups for a fixed $p$ are conjugate.  Combining these two facts, you can see that there will be a unique Sylow $p$-subgroup for each $p$.

Keep in mind that your Sylow $p$-subgroup should have order $p^{k}$, where $k$ is the largest integer such that $p^{k} \mid |G|$. Your Sylow $3$-subgroup is correct.